# LDAP failing to bind

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, phpbb, phpbb3

We have been using LDAP on a phpBB install for about 3 months now, went to login today and received a "Could not connect to LDAP server." error. I know my LDAP configuration in phpBB is correct and has not changed. I am still able to connect from my PC via Apache Directory Studio using the same configuration.

Hopefully someone with more LDAP experience can point me in the right direction. I feel like maybe there is an issue with the active directory server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the PHP-functions can not contact the LDAP-server. There might have been an update to the LDAP-Server to change the IP-Adress or a faulty DNS-entry or an update to the firewall that doesn't allow access from the webserver to the LDAP-Server.

So you see that there are some possibilities around that might influence the connection between PHPs LDAP-extension and your LDAP-Server.

When the configuration of your setup didn't change then something around it must have changed. Try to find and fix it.